# scala removing double quotes from column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to remove the double quotes in my dataframe column:

I have this:
"""test"""

I want:
test

I tried this:

```
select(regexp_replace(col("name"), """""", ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `select(regexp_replace(col("name"), "\"\"\"", ""))`?

Comment: It did, but didn't change the column name values though

Comment: This will not change the column names. This will only remove the triple quotes from within the column values..